# where went ubuntu(installed along side windows) after reinstalled windows?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

i had installed ubuntu 12.04 alongside windows 7(ultimate) creating a disk partition of 10 G. I had some problem with windows, i had to format and reinstall it. I used the same partition for windows where it resided before.But now i m not able to see the start screen which i used to see before giving me options to enter in to ubuntu and windows.How shall i get it back? what has happened to ubuntu partition? should i re install it? (Let reinstalling be last possible solution, because i have my good programs created and stored in ubuntu:(....)

Comment: you will have to recover grub... you can follow steps from here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I usually do in such "surprising" situations is to boot the box from a live CD. This enables me to look around and see what happened, save data to an external disk etc. before trying to solve the problem.

In your specific case, if you still can find the ubuntu partition, reinstalling grub2 should do the trick.